# Tring to format milliseconds in SYSTEMTIME to only show the first two digits

Tags: string, format, systemtime

Hi I'm trying to format a `string` so that I am able to get the system time to be `HH:MM:SS:MM(Milliseconds)`

I've written this

```
SYSTEMTIME time;
GetLocalTime(&time);
line.Format("%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d \n" ,time.wHour, time.wMinute, time.wSecond, time.wMilliseconds);
```

My problem is I get something like this for example: `10:17:30:210`

I really don't want the 3rd digit on the millisecond how can I truncate it to only two?

Comment: It would be very odd to show "21" - because it's not 21, it's 210. 21 would be centiseconds, not milliseconds. This is pretty much *bound* to cause confusion...

Comment: What language is this? C#? Please [edit] the question and add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can quite simply divide by 10 - `time.wMilliseconds/10`.

```
SYSTEMTIME time;
GetLocalTime(&time);
line.Format("%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d\n" ,time.wHour, time.wMinute, time.wSecond,
            time.wMilliseconds/10);
```